# Try to delete the '\n' at the end of line only if the next line begins with '('

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am tring to use Regex on Natepad++ to modify some text.

Try to delete the '\n' at the end of line only if the next line begins with '('

Example: Change

```
This is a line
(Note)
```

to

```
This is a line(Note)
```

My Regex is replacing `\n^(` or `\n(` with `(`. But it wont work.

Comment: `\n(` with Extended should work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the bracket with slash: `\(`.

So you'll replace `\r\n\(` with `\(`.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please also accept the answer, so that this queston won't be shown as ananswered.

Comment: Of course I tried to accept your answer, but it says I have to wait another 4 minutes before I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:
Find what: `$\R(`
Replace with: `\(`

Comment: I tried but it wont work either. The new line in my text  is 'LF' aka '\n' not '\r\n'.

Comment: @GabySolis: `\R` stands for `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`, and you have to add a backslash before to parens in the replacement part.

Comment: Yes, just like @streetturtle suggests, the `(` have to be escaped aka `\(`